# Memory manager implementation in C for memory blocks of 1 byte to 8k bytes - interview question

Tags: c, algorithm, memory-management

You need to implement a memory manager in C with the following 3 functions:

`void init()` - initialize the memory manager.

`void* get(int numOfBytes)` - return a memory block (on the heap) of size "numOfBytes". The value of "numOfBytes" can be in the range [1,8k].

`void free(void* ptr)` - free the memory block pointed by "ptr".

Few rules:

1. You can call for malloc function only in the "init()" function.
2. The methods "get" and "free" should be as efficient as possible, but the method "init" doesn't have to be as long as you don't waste too much memory or something like that.
3. You can assume your memory manager will not need to allocate more than some fixed size number of bytes in total, say no more than 1GB at total.

My attempt:
I thought of just implementing fixed size memory pool where each block is 8k bytes, like in [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/204406/fixed-sized-memory-pool-in-c). This will give us O(1) run time for methods "get" and "free" which is great, but the problem is that we are wasting a lot of memoy like that if the user only calls "get" for small number of bytes (say, 1 byte each time).
But if I try to implement it with variable block sizes - I'll need to handle fragmentation which will make the run time worse.

So do you have a better idea?

Comment: You suggest "fixed size ... each block is 8k bytes" but also the condition "as long as you don't waste too much memory". I have seen an implementation that keeps lists of blocks of size 2^n and splits the smallest block available to get the minimum adequate size. On freeing, the code attempted to merge with any unused consecutive memory of the same size to recover as a larger block.

Comment: `free()` is a standard lib function - best to not redefine - use a different name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd avoid a fixed size block.

A common strategy is to form pools at power-of-2: 16,32,...1G, with everything initially in the largest pool.

Each block allocated is the user size `n` + overhead (est. 4-8 bytes) "ceiling" up to a power-of-2.

If a pool lacks an available block, cut a larger one in half.

As similar allocation sizes tend to occur in groups, this avoids excess size waste.

On de-allocation (and collapsing for reuse) only requires free'ing of a pair'd block to re-form the larger block (which may in turn re-join another block) and reduce fragmentation.

Note: All `*alloc()` return a pointer OK to align `max_align_t`, thus that is the lower bound expected likewise for `get()` - (maybe size 4?).  As part of an interview, mentioning alignment and portability concerns is good.

---

There are various improves like well accommodating power-of-2 size blocks, yet for an interview question, only need to touch on such improvement ideas.

---

`free()` is a standard lib. function - best to not redefine - use a different name.